# How to click html 'button class' using selenium at python

Tags: python, selenium, button

I'd like to click the button using python selenium but have failed to do so. How to click "나중에 하기" with a code? I've tried with driver.find_element_by_link_text but didn't work... please help

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text('나중에 하기')
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

```html
button class="aOOlW  bIiDR  " tabindex="0">설정</button"
button class="aOOlW   HoLwm " tabindex="0">나중에 하기</button"
```

Comment: please show more of your code, include the relevant html using snippet tool via [edit] and the url if possible.

Answer (score 1):

`find_element_by_link_text` works only on `<a>` tags. Try to locate the element by `xpath` instead

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[.="나중에 하기"]').click()
```

Or use class instead to locate by text

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('HoLwm').click()
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could try waiting for the element to be clickable and combine css selectors for tag and class

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.HoLwm"))).click()
```

**imports**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```